# Exchange 2010: User cannot access their own mailbox

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I have a mailbox that can only be accessed by an admin account, I am unable to access it using the account it is attached to. If I delete the mailbox and create a new one and attach it to the same user I am still unable to access it with an account other than an admin account.

Environment: Exchange 2010 SP2 RU6

Comment: Need more info like `Get-MailboxPermission`, etc.  Also is the user a Domain Admin or other elevated group member?

Comment: There was no differences between the output from a user that works and this user when I ran Get-MailboxPermission. The admin account that can access the mailbox is a domain admin the account that the mailbox is attached to is a just a basic domain user.

Comment: When you say then "unable to access it"...from where?  Outlook?  Does OWA work fine?  Your question lacks a lot of detail.

Comment: Both Outlook and OWA

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the user was set to only be able to log into some systems, after adding the exchange server to the list of system the user is allowed to log on to the problem was resolved.